# Python Error No such table using sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Trying Python today for the first time today and got stuck following and example almost immediately. Using Pyhon 3.6 on Windows. Can someone help?

```
RESTART: C:/Users/tom_/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Projects/Database/dbexample.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tom_/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Projects/Database/dbexample.py", line 13, in <module>
    enter_data()
  File "C:/Users/tom_/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Projects/Database/dbexample.py", line 11, in enter_data
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Example VALUES('Python', 2.7, 'Beginner')")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Example
```

Code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE Example(Language VARCHAR, Version REAL, Skill TEXT)")

def enter_data():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Example VALUES('Python', 2.7, 'Beginner')")

enter_data()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `create_table()` **once** before you can use `enter_data()` for a new db. 
Once it has been created you will get a `sqlite3.OperationalError: table Example already exists` if you call it again.

Comment: Oh, I get it. That is just a definition of a function that I need to call first. Thank you.